# UILabelのテキスト変更時にテキスト変更のアニメションをさせない方法

Tags: ios, uilabel

UILabel(とUILabelを子として持つView)の表示位置をアニメーションさせると通常アニメーションされないテキストの変更もアニメーションされてしまいます。

下記がサンプルコードです。

```
- (void)showErrorViewWithErrorText:(NSString *)errorText {
    // エラービューに表示する文字列を設定、エラービューはUILabelを子として持つ
    self.errorView.errorText = errorText;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                     animations:^{
                         // 画面外にあるエラービューを表示するために制約値を変更
                         self.errorViewToNicknameConstraint.constant = 55.0;                                                     
                         [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```

現状ですとエラービューが表示される時に、エラービューに表示されるLabelの文字が古い文字から新しい文字に変更するようにアニメーションがかかってしまいエラーの表示が分かりにくいです。

テキスト変更に対するアニメーション防止方法ご存知でしたらご教授いただきたく。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決できました。

新規テキスト入力後、何もアニメーションさせないアニメーションを実施し（分かりづらい日本語ですね）、その完了後に本当にアニメーションさせたい処理を記述します。

下記がそのコード例です

```
- (void)showErrorViewWithErrorText:(NSString *)errorText {
    // エラービューに表示する文字列を設定
    self.inputErrorView.errorText = errorText;
    // 何もしないアニメーション
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0
                     animations:^{

    }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         // ここに本当のアニメーション
                         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                                               delay:0.0
                                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone
                                          animations:^{
                                              // 画面外にあるエラービューを表示するために制約値を変更
                                              self.inputErrorViewToNicknameConstraint.constant = 55.0;
                                              [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
                                          }
                                          completion:^(BOOL finished) {

                                          }];
                     }];
    }
```